# Can I use timeouts in cURL to avoid a connection hang?

Tags: curl, connection, php-curl, lsof

In a cron process, I use cURL to get information from an API.  Sometimes the cron process freezes/hangs because of an issue with the API connection.

When I do an strace -p pID, the process is just polling an fd resource and then timesout repeatedly.

When I do an lsof -p pID, I see that the fd resource mentioned in the strace has an entry like this:

php     26942 root    8u  IPv4 1853797972        0t0        TCP ip-XX-X-XX-XXX.ec2.internal:XXXXX->13.68.25.XXX:https (ESTABLISHED)

Nothing else is after this entry.

It appears that something is happening with the TCP connection to the API. 
 Which timeout option for cURL can I use to avoid having my cron process hang at this point in the cURL transaction?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as well. Did you find a solution?